# how can i interpret max(stats,key=stats.get) where stats is some dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

we define a dictionary:

```
stats = {'a':1000, 'b':3000, 'c': 100}
```

Then I want to find the key with the highest value, i use:

```
 max(stats,key=stats.get)
```

I understand that key is the thing max() is trying to maximise, but what exactly is stats.get? writing stats.get in python returns:

```
<built-in method get of dict object at 0x7fd6c2d6b240>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Return the element x from stats for which stats.get(x) is maximal"*

`stats.get` is the [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method [bound](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects) to the [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) instance `stats`. [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) will apply that function to each element in the iterable, e.g. `stats.get('a')`, and use the returned values as sorting keys (e.g. `1000` for `'a'`). Note that iterating a `dict` produces its keys. Hence, the above will return the key with the largest value (`'b'`).